# How do I install HP F4180?

Tags: hp, ubuntu-drivers

I need to install HP Deskjet F4180 drivers's. I'm new using Ubuntu and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: what version of Ubuntu is this

Comment: recent distros will already have hplip and will allow you to install the printer by name. I just installed F2100 series with KDE printer installation dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what version of Ubuntu your using, but two things:

1. Plugin the printer then open tha address `127.0.0.1:631` in your browser.

   a. Select `Administration menu` and click on `Find New Printers`

   b. If your printer is present then go ahead and click on `Add This Printer`

   c. If your printer isn't listed then go to `step 2`
2. Go [here](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install_wizard/index.html) and enter your system and printer information

   a. Click next and download the required printer drivers.

   b. Read through the instructions on how to install it, you will have to return to the download page to access the documentation.

   - This would be `sh hplip-3.17.9.run` from a terminal, but read through first before embarking.

Comment: Great please the accept the answer